# Python Pandas DataFrame difficulties flattening after GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, Date, Time and Usage. The times are in 15 minute intervals (some intervals may/will be missing). The Date column lists every day in the month (possible to have more than one month).

The goal is to sum up the usage values by hour per day per month. I was able to accomplish this with a groupby, but it creates a multi-index Series. When I try adding "reset_index()" to the end of my groupby I get an error since I am using the same column twice (once by month and once by day). I have a feeling I need to alias my columns so I can then flatten the multi-index but I'm not sure how.

*note I know I can just create "helper" columns for the day and hour and use those in my groupby, but I was hoping to not have to do that.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Interval Data', sep=';')

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
df = df[['END_TIME', 'USAGE_DATE', 'USAGE']]
df['END_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_TIME'])
df['USAGE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['USAGE_DATE'])

grp_df = df.groupby([df.USAGE_DATE.dt.month, df.USAGE_DATE.dt.day, df.END_TIME.dt.hour])['USAGE'].sum()

print(grp_df.head())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename your multi-index. Try:

`grp_df.index.rename(['month1', 'day1', 'hour2'], inplace = True)`

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.rename.html

Comment: Thank you. That worked with a little finessing. Any way to get this down to a single line of code with the groupby?

code using your suggestion:

`code
grp_df = df.groupby([df.USAGE_DATE.dt.month, df.USAGE_DATE.dt.day, df.END_TIME.dt.hour])['USAGE'].sum()

grp_df.index.rename(['Month', 'Day', 'Hour'], inplace=True)

grp_df = grp_df.reset_index()


print(grp_df.head())
`

Comment: ``grp_df = df.groupby([df.USAGE_DATE.dt.month, df.USAGE_DATE.dt.day, df.END_TIME.dt.hour])['USAGE'].sum().rename_axis(index = ['Month', 'Day', 'Hour']).reset_index()`` is a one-liner but it creates readability issues and I wouldn't really do that unless you absolutely need to fit everything in one line.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I mostly wanted the one-liner to understand the structure. having it split still works and saves me having to create/drop columns. Really appreciate the fast replies.